# Efficient data transformation

Tags: arrays, ruby

I've got a data format like this, array `a` :

```
[{
  agreement_id: 1,
  app_user_id: 1,
  agency_name: 'Small business 1'
},
{
  agreement_id: 1,
  app_user_id: 2,
  agency_name: 'Small business 1'
},
{
  agreement_id: 2,
  app_user_id: 1,
  agency_name: 'Small business 2'
}]
```

I've obviously simplified the array elements, I actually have the list or AR objects, but gist of it should be the same.

I m basically looking to create a user to agreement map. By that I mean this output:

```
    [{
      agreement_id: 1,
      app_users: [1, 2],
      agency_name: 'Small business 1'
    },
    {
      agreement_id: 2,
      app_user_id: [1],
      agency_name: 'Small business 2'
    }]
```

Here is how I wanted to do that (psuedo code) :

- Instantiate a ruby Hash `h`
- Create array `b`
- Iterate over array `a`
- for each element of the array (`elem`), check if `h` does not have  `elem[:agreement_id]` key, then create new property on the `elem` called `app_users` and put `[elem[: app_user_id]]` as a value in the new property (array of one value).

Then push `elem` without `app_user_id` property to the array b.

Then we iterate over the next element `elem` and if it doesn't have `elem[:agreement_id]` key we do the same thing as described above.

However if `h` has `elem[:agreement_id]` key, append `elem[: app_user_id]` to the `app_users` property array. Then push `elem` without `app_user_id` property to the array b.

Is there a more shorthand approach to accomplish the same thing, more inline with existing ruby methods?

Comment: Will `customer_name` and `agency_name` always be the same for the same `agreement_id`?

Comment: Also, is it a mix of `customer_name` and `agency_name`, or is that a typo?

Comment: @EddeAlmeida yes they will

Comment: @EricDuminil yes it was I m sorry I ll edit

Comment: When you said you'd edit, did you not mean to change the key `:customer_name` to `:agency_name`? When you give an example it's helpful to assign a variable to each input object, so that readers can refer to those variables in answers and comments without having to define them. You did say that the array was `a`--which is good--but it's slightly preferable to write `a = [{  agreement_id:..]`, so that the variable is front-and-centre and readers can then just cut and paste to run your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume (as others have) that the key `:customer_name` in the OP's example should be `:agency_name` and that the values of `:agency_name` are the same for all hashes with the same value of `:agreement_id`.

```
h = [{
  agreement_id: 1,
  app_user_id: 1,
  agency_name: 'Small business 1'
},
{
  agreement_id: 1,
  app_user_id: 2,
  agency_name: 'Small business 1'
},
{
  agreement_id: 2,
  app_user_id: 1,
  agency_name: 'Small business 2'
}]
```

```
h.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  h.update(g[:agreement_id]=>{ agreement_id: g[:agreement_id],
                               app_user_id:   [g[:app_user_id]],
                               agency_name:   g[:agency_name]
                             }
          ) do |_,o,n| { agreement_id: o[:agreement_id],
                         app_user_id:  o[:app_user_id] + n[:app_user_id],
                         agency_name:    o[:agency_name]
                       }
            end
end.values
  #=> [{:agreement_id=>1, :app_user_id=>[1, 2], :agency_name=>"Small business 1"},
  #    {:agreement_id=>2, :app_user_id=>[1], :agency_name=>"Small business 2"}]
```

This uses the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that employs a block to compute the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. See the doc for a further explanation, particularly the contents of each of the block's three keys. (I've used an underscore for the first of those keys--the common key--to signify that it is not used in the block calculation.)

Comment: looks like your way is the fastest, check out my answer for benchmarks.Thanks

Answer (score 3):

A mix of [`group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), [`values_at`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-values_at) and [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) should bring you closer to your goal.

This code groups hashes together that have the same values for `agreement_id` and `agency_name`.

The output key is always `:app_user_ids` even if the array contains one single element, and the first `customer_name` has been renamed to `agency_name` :

```
data = [{
  agreement_id: 1,
  app_user_id: 1,
  agency_name: 'Small business 1'
},
{
  agreement_id: 1,
  app_user_id: 2,
  agency_name: 'Small business 1'
},
{
  agreement_id: 2,
  app_user_id: 1,
  agency_name: 'Small business 2'
}]

puts data.group_by{ |hash|
  hash.values_at(:agreement_id, :agency_name)
}.map{ |(agreement_id, agency_name), hashes|
  {
    agreement_id: agreement_id,
    agency_name: agency_name,
    app_user_ids: hashes.map { |h| h[:app_user_id] }
  }
}
# {:agreement_id=>1, :agency_name=>"Small business 1", :app_user_ids=>[1, 2]}
# {:agreement_id=>2, :agency_name=>"Small business 2", :app_user_ids=>[1]}
```

Comment: What are parenthesis here for? `map{ |(agreement_id, agency_name), hashes|`

Comment: `group_by` is used with an array of 2 elements. This is a way to get those 2 elements directly in the block arguments. `map{|pair,hashes| id, name = pair; }` could be used otherwise.

Comment: Thanks. What's the name of  that technique / syntax? I want to look it up.

Comment: Good question. I learned it by looking at code on SO, and I don't know how it's called. Possibly [destructuring](http://tony.pitluga.com/2011/08/08/destructuring-with-ruby.html)

Comment: @EricDuminil what if I have more attributes than `agreement_id, agency_name` that repeat for every app user? Do I just add them to the paranthesis in the ||

Comment: @Remember_me: If you want to group by those attributes, yes you could.

Comment: @EricDuminil looks like your answer is faster than mine, check out my answer for benchmarks.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers, I did this in the meantime, I didn't see responses. This is my solution :

```
json_map = {}

[{
  agreement_id: 1,
  app_user_id: 1,
  agency_name: 'Small business 1'
},
{
  agreement_id: 1,
  app_user_id: 2,
  agency_name: 'Small business 1'
},
{
  agreement_id: 2,
  app_user_id: 1,
  agency_name: 'Small business 2'
}].each do |ag_deal|
  app_user_id = ag_deal[:app_user_id]
  agreement_id = ag_deal[:agreement_id]

  if json_map.key?(agreement_id)
    ag_deal = json_map[agreement_id]
    ag_deal[:app_user_ids] << app_user_id
  else
    ag_deal[:app_user_ids] = [app_user_id]
    json_map[agreement_id] = ag_deal.except(:app_user_id)
  end
end
```

So the desired result is in `json_map.values`, paste :

```
[
  {:agreement_id=>1, :agency_name=>"Small business 1", :app_user_ids=>[1, 2]},
  {:agreement_id=>2, :agency_name=>"Small business 2", :app_user_ids=>[1]}
]
```

I m going to benchmark these and use the fastest one, I m going to create a 1000 items in the array with couple of random users, that should hopefully simulate it right.

And here are my benchmarking results :

```
=======Cary ======
user     system      total        real
0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.008853)

=====Eric====
user     system      total        real
0.020000   0.010000   0.030000 (  0.017856) 

====me=====
user     system      total        real
0.010000   0.030000   0.040000 (  0.020826)
```

This is how sample data was generated :

```
users = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
data = []
1000.times do |i|
  data << {
    agreement_id: i,
    app_user_id: users.shuffle.first,
    agency_name: "Small business #{i}"
  }
end
```

Comment: You should use each instead of map.